# Table height:100% not working in chrome, safari, opera

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, mozilla

I code a following design

CSS

```
#content1{
top:0;
width: 300px;
height: 250px;

}

#content2{
width: 300px;
height: 250px;

}

#content3{
width: 300px;
height: 250px;

}

#bottom{
width: 300px;
height: 75px;

}
```

code

```
<td width="300" valign="top" style="height:100%;">


      <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  height="100%">
       <tr>  
        <td valign="top">
         <div id="content1>/*****Content1****/</div>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td valign="middle">
         <div id="content2/*****Content2****/</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td valign="middle">
        <div id="content3/*****Content3****/</div>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td valign="bottom">
        <div id="bottom/*****Content4****/</div>
       </td>
     </tr>
    </table>

 </td>
```

You can see this in here working 
http://www.spoiledagent.com/about_karu1.html

It is working perfectly as I wanted it with equal margins on both the browsers IE and Mozilla but it is not looking good in any other browser like Safari, Chrome etc. all the blocks are looking stick together.

How can we make it look same on all browsers as it is coming on IE

Thanks

Comment: you could but them in a <ul><li></li></ul> situation and give them a margin-top on the li.

Comment: it's probably best if you don't use a table for laying out the page. It's considered bad practice, and it's likely to be contributing toward the problem.

Comment: have you tried my fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Give your table an id and use this css.

```
#tableid
{
border-collapse:separate;
border-spacing:0 20px;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rA25h/)
For more information read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-spacing)

Comment: Its still not working, it is working fine in firefox and IE but not on other browsers

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you put them into a list`?`

here is a little [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSLWS/) for you